# uzbl-tabbed keyboard shortcut for closing tabs?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, uzbl

I can open tabs by typing "gn" I can change them by using "gt" and "gT". But I can't close tabs from within in the browser.

I looked at the [Readme](http://www.uzbl.org/readme.php) and that stuff is way over my head. I don't know if any of that information would answer my question anyway.

I found this [wiki](http://www.uzbl.org/wiki/uzbl_tabbed) which I couldn't understand. It says there's a .py that communicates to the configuration file which I don't quite understand. I don't know anything about python and I can't find the configuration file. Plus, I just thought I could use a simple keyboard shortcut while using the browser anyway.

I also found [the commands document](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/UZBL-Browser#Commands) which tells me pretty much everything I was looking for except how to close a tab.

Plus, when I close uzbl-tabbed and open it again, all the tabs are open from the previous session so I can't even get rid of them by closing uzbl.

The answer seems to be right in front of my face but I can't seem to figure it out. Please help.

Comment: [this](http://www.uzbl.org/wiki/uzbl_tabbed?s[]=tabs) suggests it's `gC` to close a tab and `gQ` to close all tabs. If not you could try their [mailing list](http://www.uzbl.org/community.php).

Comment: Thank you, Sam! That's exactly what I was looking for. Now, to respect the values of this forum as being programming-orientated, should I delete this discussion somehow or move it to another place? If not, how do I mark this as solved and vote your answer to be the solution?

Comment: @Sam please consider moving that comment to an answer